# Yii2 Models Validations

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on Yii2, however I have a model this model have some attributes, some are required on insert/create mode and some are required on update mode, let say mode = scenario, So I created a Form model with 2 scenarios insert and update, then I set validation rules for the attributes as the scenario, the question is: shall I define the scenarios in both models(Active Record and Form Model)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Scenarios should be defined in your model ..

and you should set the scenario youwant use in your related action

```
    public function  actionUpdate(){

    ....

    $model->scenario = 'update';
    ...
```

Comment: I know, my question is shall I define the scenarios twice in the Active Record model and inside Form Model?

Comment: If the Form Model is derived from  an ActiveRecord Model then the declaration is only in ActiveREcord model

Comment: Form Model extends Model class, and Entity Model extends Active Record, but if I extends the form model from the entity model this will inherits the scenarios and validation rules? then what is the value if Form Model?

Comment: Should be so ..  if you extend one class form another you should inherit from parent .. ... included scenarios

Comment: scaisEdge, why if we define scenarios and validation in Active Record model why we need to do that inside Form Model Also?

Comment: I don't understand your comment  .. if the scenario is defined in active record  and the form model is derived (extended) from the active record  the scenario don't should redefined  because is inherit ...otherwise if the form model is not  derived form active record then the scenario  is not defined for this class and you must declare  ..

Answer (score 0):

```
    ActiveRecord read from the database has the "update" scenario, while a new record has the "insert" scenario.
    $modelA = User::model()->findByPk(1); // $model->scenario = 'update'
    $modelB = new User();                 // $model->scenario = 'insert'
    $modelB->scenario = 'light';          // custom scenario
    if ($modelB->validate()) {            // will only apply rules of the "light" scenario
     ...............
     ..............
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, in your model:

```
class YourModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';
    const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';

...
public function scenarios(){
    $scenarios = parent::scenarios();
    $scenarios[static::SCENARIO_CREATE] = ['field_1', 'field_2'];
    $scenarios[static::SCENARIO_UPDATE] = ['field_1', 'field_3'];
    return $scenarios;
}

...
}
```

In Your conttroller:

```
class YourController extends Controller {

...

    public function actionCreate(){
        $model = new YourModel()

        $model->scenario = YourModel::SCENARIO_CREATE;

        if($model->validate()){ // validate fields specifed in YourModel SCENARIO_CREATE
            ...
        }

        ...
    }

...

    public function actionUpdate(){
        $model = new YourModel()

        $model->scenario = YourModel::SCENARIO_UPDATE;

        if($model->validate()){ // validate fields specifed in YourModel SCENARIO_UPDATE 
            ...
        }

        ...
    }

}
```

If my answer helpful, please put a tick))

Comment: Hi Vitaly, I know how to use it, the question above about why to use 2 models and define the scenarios twice in model and form?